# Using dropdown menus in tabs in Android

Tags: android, listview, menu, tabs

I'm a beginner in using Android. I'm trying to create an activity which contains 4 tabs (I'm using Google's `SlidingTabLayout`). One of the tabs is the "category" tab.

For this tab, I'm trying to have 5 options as a drop down menu. So I want the "category" tab to be selected by default and it shows 5 types and then when the user clicks one of the category types, a list view of corresponding category type will be shown.

Comment: What you have searched?

Comment: I'v searched about menus and tabs and how can I combine menus and tabs, etc.

Comment: You can add spinner for category in category tab

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion showing a drop down from one of the sliding tabs is a not a good and proper way.I think you should use Navigation Drawer for categories and the other corresponding category items should be shown in sliding tabs.Remove Category tab from sliding menu and show categories in Navigation Drawer and the corresponding sub categories should be in sliding tabs.That will be proper way and easy to manage.I think this will be a good idea.